# In a Self Join, Remove Line with the same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My Code.

This is to join mistake done by employees when creating Credit Documet References the "Link" is what join them together but the credit "Doc_ref" are normally the same but sometime 2 are created splitting the Credits.

I use the Doc_ref to View any returns linked to it. so that's my dilemma

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.LINE_ID, CASE
    WHEN  POSITIVE.Doc_Ref = B.Link AND A.Link = B.Link AND A.Doc_Ref != B.Doc_Ref AND A.Principal_Ref != B.Principal_Ref AND A.Outlet_Name = B.Outlet_Name  THEN rtrim(A.[Doc_Ref]) + ' | ' + rtrim(B.[Doc_Ref]) 
    ELSE A.Doc_Ref
END AS Doc_Ref,
 A.Glue_Code, A.CCN_Name,  A.Doc_Date, A.Outlet_Code, A.Outlet_Name, 
A.Link, A.Principal_Ref

FROM NEGITIVE A, NEGITIVE B, POSITIVE WHERE A.Doc_Ref != B.Doc_Ref AND A.Link = B.Link  ORDER BY Doc_Ref
```

My Result

```
474 ABP0008918 | ABP0008919 GPT05610    PTA 2021-05-04  15078428 
474 ABP0008918 GPT05610    PTA 2021-05-04  15078428 
475 ABP0008919 | ABP0008918 GPT05610    PTA 2021-05-04  15078428 
475 ABP0008919 GPT05610    PTA 2021-05-04  15078428
```

What I would like to see is Just

```
474 ABP0008918 | ABP0008919 GPT05610    PTA 2021-05-04  15078428  
475 ABP0008918 | ABP0008919 GPT05610    PTA 2021-05-04  15078428
```

Note that the Doc_Ref must look the same after the query is completed.

Thank you.

Comment: Evolve! No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you showed the tables and the content.

But it looks like you do not have any join-condition for POSITIVE resulting in an Cartesian join.

Try adding a "AND A.LINK = POSITIVE.Doc_Ref" to the WHERE-clause:

```
FROM NEGITIVE A, NEGITIVE B, POSITIVE 
WHERE A.Doc_Ref != B.Doc_Ref 
AND A.Link = B.Link 
AND A.LINK = POSITIVE.Doc_Ref
ORDER BY Doc_Ref
```